# breaking a mathematical using a regex code

Tags: regex, scala

I have a math problem as a string such as "2 * 3 (2 +4) and want to split it into an array of 2,*,3,(,2,+,4,) and also make sure it leaves out whitespace. i believe that it is dropping the parenthesis

ive tried a few regex codes but as i am new they dont seem to work. This one definitely finds the parenthesis but the function i am using i believe is dropping them.

```
var Prob : Array[String]= Problem.split("([\\s  () ])")
```

not sure how i can include the parenthesis in my array

Comment: Why you need it? There are no solutions? I'm think there are.
https://github.com/facaiy/math-expression-parser

Comment: !but the function i am using i believe is dropping them." WHat do you mean by this? If the example regexp is working, then it's the function that is the problem, but we will need more details of that to be able to help

Answer (score 0):

You could use search to in effect 'split' string into numbers and operators. I'm not really familiar with Scala but I tried this in python and it seems to work.

```
re.findall(r"\d+|\W","123+45*(4-88)")
```

Output : ['123', '+', '45', '*', '(', '4', '-', '88', ')']

Comment: yes but the problem with that is if i have -4 + 8 its going to separate the - and the 4

Comment: I think we only need to handle the case of '-', if it is already preceded by an operator, right?

Comment: the first number entered could also be negative

Comment: re.findall(r"(?<!\d)-\d+|\W|\d+","-123+-45*(4-88)")

Comment: r"(?<!\d)[+-]\d+|\W|\d+"    will also handle + similar to the -